# xamarin android emulator not able to start

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-emulator

I am unable to run my Xamarin project in the android emulator there is no start button just an error. The repair option is grayed out and the only option I can do is Duplicate which says I need to repair? if I try and install a new device I get an image failed message.

> Is there anyway to fix this? Or delete and reinstall?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it on windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select x86 instead of x86. HAXM works with x86
- Check your installed SDKs in Android SDK manager within Visual Studio
  if API 28 is missing download it. You need below 3 highlighted in order for x86-64 to work
  [image]

If above doesnt work

- Best option now is to repair Visual Studio with Android SDK
- If that does not work uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.